# Angular material table adding an extra row for each record, While implementing the expansion of rows code in angular 9

Tags: angular-material, angular9

I am at initial stage in learning angular 9.I have a mat-table which is having an icon for each row,and I am trying to write code such that on click of icon the particular row should be expanded. My following code is working fine but on load of the page, an extra row is being added to each record in

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Candidate } from '.././Models/candidate.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidates',
  templateUrl: './candidates.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candidates.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class CandidatesComponent implements OnInit {


  columnsToDisplay: string[] = ['arrow', 'reference', 'name', 'date', 'grade', 'location', 'status', 'action'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  expandedElement: Candidate | null;

  categories = [
    { value: 'category', viewValue: 'category' },
    { value: 'C1', viewValue: 'grade3' },
    { value: 'C2', viewValue: 'grade4' },
    { value: 'C3A', viewValue: 'grade2' },
  ];

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.loginService.getCandidates().subscribe(results => {
    //   console.log("inisde candidate ts ===>", results);
    //   if (!results) { return };
    //   this.dataSource.data = results;
    // });
    this.dataSource.data=[
      {
          "referenceId": "ENk2N789",
          "firstName": "heidi",
          "middleName": null,
          "lastName": null,
          "grade": "ITA",
          "location": "Chennai",
          "status": "New",
          "emailId": "heidi@gmail.com",
          "phone": "97 9884729272",
          "empId": "135124",
          "reportingAddress": "Chennai Siruseri",
          "startDate": "2020-07-06T16:48:33.743+00:00",
          "confirmDate": null,
          "taggedBuddy": "yes",
          "isExpanded" : false
      },
      {
          "referenceId": "QWK2N789",
          "firstName": "nemo",
          "middleName": null,
          "lastName": null,
          "grade": "C!",
          "location": "Hyderabad",
          "status": "New",
          "emailId": "nemo@gmail.com",
          "phone": "97 9245367234",
          "empId": "123456",
          "reportingAddress": "Chennai Siruseri",
          "startDate": "2020-07-06T16:48:33.743+00:00",
          "confirmDate": null,
          "taggedBuddy": "yes",
          "isExpanded" : false
      },
      {
          "referenceId": "ESR2N789",
          "firstName": "minion",
          "middleName": null,
          "lastName": null,
          "grade": "ITA",
          "location": "Chennai",
          "status": "New",
          "emailId": "minion@tcs.com",
          "phone": "97 9245677234",
          "empId": "1332130",
          "reportingAddress": "Chennai Siruseri",
          "startDate": "2020-07-06T16:48:33.743+00:00",
          "confirmDate": null,
          "taggedBuddy": "yes",
          "isExpanded" : false
      }
  ]

  }

  approveCandidate() {
    console.log("approve ta gbuddy");
  }
  tagBuddy() {
    console.log("gettign ta gbuddy");
  }

}
```

```css
.table-bg1{
  top: 57px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1366px;
  height: 268px;
  background: url('../../assets/images/Diversity-Img.png') rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  margin-top: 57px;   
//opacity: 0.36;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.cand_heading{
  top: 152px;
  left: 165px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 61px;
  text-align: center;
  font: Bold 50px/61px Calibri;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #FFFEFE;
  position: absolute;
  //opacity: 1;
}
.table-bg2{
    top: 325px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 702px;
    background: url('../../assets/images/shutterstock_709202158.png') rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;  
    // opacity: 0.36;
}
.table_layout{
    top: 484px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 1296px;
    height: 393px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 47px 47px 38px 38px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 21px 40px 89px 30px;
}
.table_header{
  top: 484px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 1296px;
  height: 62px;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #2B74F3 0%, #163A7A 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 38px 38px 0px 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 286px;
    padding: 5px;
}

  /* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.approve_link {
    top: 558px;
    left: 1104px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font: Regular 14px/20px Source Sans Pro;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #2D81B7;
    opacity: 1;
}
.buddy_tag_link {
    top: 559px;
    left: 1189px;
    width: 101px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font: Regular 14px/20px Source Sans Pro;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #2D81B7;
    opacity: 1;
}
.catg_dd{
  top: 389px;
  left: 111px;
  width: 315px;
  height: 42px;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  border-radius: 21px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 64px 43px 0px 81px;   
}
.ref_id_input {
    top: 389px;
    left: 469px;
    width: 315px;
    height: 42px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 21px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 64px 43px 0px 0px;
}
.records_dd{
  top: 389px;
  left: 827px;
  width: 173px;
  height: 42px;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  border-radius: 21px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 64px 43px 0px 0px;
}
.search {
  top: 389px;
  left: 1043px;
  width: 173px;
  height: 42px;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #21BF36 0%, #11601B 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 21px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 64px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.export_btn {
  top: 962px;
  left: 53px;
  width: 173px;
  height: 42px;
  color: white;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #21BF36 0%, #11601B 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 21px;
  margin: 0px 0px 23px 53px;
  opacity: 1;
}
mat-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.expandIcon{
  left: 53px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background:#149AEF  0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
//table css properties
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr.candidate-detail-row {
  height: 0;
}

tr.candidate-element-row:not(.candidate-expanded-row):hover {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

tr.candidate-element-row:not(.candidate-expanded-row):active {
  background: #efefef;
}

.candidate-element-row td {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}

.candidate-element-detail {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 3px 8px #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="table-bg1">
    <span class="cand_heading">Candidates</span>
</div>
<div class="table-bg2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column catg_dd">
            <mat-form-field class="">
                <mat-select>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.value">
                        {{ category.viewValue }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="column ref_id_input">
            <mat-form-field class="">
                <mat-label>Reference ID</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Reference ID" value="">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="column records_dd">
            <mat-form-field class="">
                <mat-select>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.value">
                        {{ category.viewValue }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="column search">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <table mat-table class="table_layout" [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
            <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="arrow">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header></th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <mat-icon class="expandIcon" (click)="element.isExpanded = !element.isExpanded">
                        {{expandedElement === element ? '-' : '+'}}</mat-icon>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="reference">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Reference</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.referenceId}}
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firstName}}
                    {{element.middleName}} {{element.lastName}}
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let  element"> {{element.startDate |date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="grade">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Grade</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let  element"> {{element.grade}} </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Location</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.location}} </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let  element"> {{element.status}} </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Action</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <a (click)="approveCandidate()" class="approve_link">Approve</a>
                    <a (click)="tagBuddy()" class="buddy_tag_link">Buddy Tagging</a>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Template for details row -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
                    <div class="row candidate-element-detail"
                        [@detailExpand]="element.isExpanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 150px;">
                            <div class="column">
                                <span> Email ID: {{element.emailId}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <span> Employee ID: {{element.empId}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <span> Start Date:{{element.startDate |date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 150px;">
                            <div class="column">
                                <span> Phone: {{element.phone}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <p>Reporting Address: {{element.reportingAddress}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <span>Confirmation Date:{{element.confirmDate |date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay;sticky: true" class="table_header"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;" class="candidate-element-row"
                [class.candidate-expanded-row]="element.isExpanded"></tr>

            <!-- Extra row to show detail content column -->
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="candidate-detail-row"></tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <button class="export_btn">Export</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

the table.
Anyone please see my code and help me If I am doing anything wrong or missing something.
[table on load of the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LahJO.png)

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Candidate } from '.././Models/candidate.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidates',
  templateUrl: './candidates.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candidates.component.scss'],
   animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed, void', style({ height: '0px',visibility: 'hidden'  })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '*'})),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
      transition('expanded <=> void', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)'))
    ]),
  ],
})
export class CandidatesComponent implements OnInit {

  
  columnsToDisplay: string[] = ['arrow','reference', 'name', 'date', 'grade', 'location', 'status', 'action'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Candidate>();
  expandedElement: Candidate | null;
 
  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,private eleRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.loginService.getCandidates().subscribe(results => {
      console.log("inisde candidate ts ===>", results);
      if (!results) { return };
      this.dataSource.data = results;
    });
    console.log("this after table displayed expanele on init",this.expandedElement);
  }
}
```

```css
  .table-bg1{
    top: 57px;
left: 0px;
width: 1366px;
height: 268px;
background: url('../../assets/images/Diversity-Img.png') #000000 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
//opacity: 0.36;
}
.cand_heading{
    top: 152px;
left: 165px;
width: 230px;
height: 61px;
text-align: center;
font: Bold 50px/61px Calibri;
letter-spacing: 0px;
color: #FFFEFE;
//opacity: 1;
}
.table-bg2{
    top: 325px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 702px;
    background: url('../../assets/images/shutterstock_709202158.png') #000000 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  // opacity: 0.36;
}
.table_layout{
    top: 484px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 1296px;
    height: 393px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 47px 47px 38px 38px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 21px 40px 89px 30px;
}
.table_header{
    top: 484px;
left: 30px;
width: 1296px;
height: 62px;
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #2B74F3 0%, #163A7A 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 38px 38px 0px 0px;
opacity: 1;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 286px;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  /* Clearfix (clear floats) */
  .row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
  }
 
  thead{
    border-radius: 47px 47px;
  }
  
  .approve_link{
    top: 558px;
    left: 1104px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font: Regular 14px/20px Source Sans Pro;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #2D81B7;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .buddy_tag_link{
    top: 559px;
    left: 1189px;
    width: 101px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font: Regular 14px/20px Source Sans Pro;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #2D81B7;
    opacity: 1;

  }
  .catg_dd{
    top: 389px;
left: 111px;
width: 315px;
height: 42px;
background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border: 1px solid #707070;
border-radius: 21px;
opacity: 1;
margin: 64px 43px 0px 81px;
  }
  .ref_id_input{
    top: 389px;
    left: 469px;
    width: 315px;
    height: 42px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 21px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 64px 43px 0px 0px;
  }
  .records_dd{
    top: 389px;
left: 827px;
width: 173px;
height: 42px;
background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border: 1px solid #707070;
border-radius: 21px;
opacity: 1;
margin: 64px 43px 0px 0px;
  }
  .search{
    top: 389px;
left: 1043px;
width: 173px;
height: 42px;
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #21BF36 0%, #11601B 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 21px;
opacity: 1;
margin: 64px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  ::ng-deep .mat-select-content{
    width:2000px;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 10px;   
}
.export_btn{
  top: 962px;
left: 53px;
width: 173px;
height: 42px;
color: white;
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #21BF36 0%, #11601B 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 21px;
margin: 0px 0px 23px 53px;
opacity: 1;
}
.ic_add_circle{
  top: 680px;
left: 53px;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
opacity: 1;
}
//expansion properties
// .example-detail-row {
//   height: 0;
// }
// .example-element-detail {
//   overflow: hidden;
//   display: flex;
// }
// .example-element-description {
//   padding: 16px;
// }
.element-row {
  position: relative;
}

.element-row:not(.expanded):hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.element-row.expanded {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

i:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
//tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt


mat-row.example-detail-row {
  height: 0;
}

// mat-row.example-element-row:not(.example-expanded-row):hover {
//   background: rgb(46, 235, 8);
// }

mat-row.example-element-row:not(.example-expanded-row):active {
  background: grey;
}

.example-element-row mat-cell {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}

// .example-element-detail {
//   overflow: hidden;
//   display: flex;
// }

mat-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.expandIcon{
  left: 53px;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background:#149AEF  0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
opacity: 1;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="table-bg1">
    <span class="cand_heading">Candidates</span>
</div>
<div class="table-bg2">

    <div class="row">
        <mat-table class="table_layout" [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
            <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="arrow">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header></mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <mat-icon class="expandIcon"
                        (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
                        {{expandedElement === element ? '-' : '+'}}</mat-icon>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="reference">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Reference</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.referenceId}}
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firstName}}
                    {{element.middleName}} {{element.lastName}}
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let  element"> {{element.startDate |date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="grade">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Grade</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let  element"> {{element.grade}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Location</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.location}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let  element"> {{element.status}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Action</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <a href="" class="approve_link">Approve</a>
                    <a href="" class="buddy_tag_link">Buddy Tagging</a>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
                    <div class="example-element-detail"
                        [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
                        [style.height]="element == expandedElement ? 'unset' : '0 !important'">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 150px;">
                            <div class="column">
                                <span> Email ID: {{element.emailId}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <span> Employee ID: {{element.empId}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <span> Start Date:{{element.startDate |date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 150px;">
                            <div class="column">
                                <span> Phone: {{element.phone}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <p>Reporting Address: {{element.reportingAddress}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <span>Confirmation Date:{{element.confirmDate |date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay" class="table_header"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;" class="example-element-row"
                [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element">
            </mat-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <button class="export_btn">Export</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to run your code successfully by copy it, if you can put in stackblitz i can check again, meanwhile you can have a look to the similar functionality example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows)

Comment: May I know how to add the code in stackblitz or any other platform to provide my code.

Comment: @sravani6569 Here is all information which might be helpful - https://stackblitz.com/docs, you may also choose above example on stackblitz in previous comment, try to fork it and edit as per your requirements to see results, good luck

Comment: Thank you so much for the document link..!!Sure, next time on wards will make use of stackblitz.

Comment: @sravani6569 Great, You have to accept or mark which of answer's above is useful in your findings or helped to reach maximum expected results, thanks

Answer (score -1):

From above code, the approach to create material table is with `display:flex` style, and not native HTML table. 
With reference to
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#tables-with-display-flex

But the above documentation also suggest :

> Note that this approach means you cannot include certain native-table features such colspan/rowspan or have columns that resize themselves based on their content.

You might also facing issue because few features are not working properly in this alternate approach.

So try to make the table native HTML type.

Here is an example : [example](https://www.freakyjolly.com/expand-collapse-single-or-multiple-rows-in-angular-98-material-table-multiple-single/)

Comment: I tried the same as mentioned in this example link[link] (https://www.freakyjolly.com/expand-collapse-single-or-multiple-rows-in-angular-98-material-table-multiple-single/#Demo_Link) but I am getting the following error
core.js:4081 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isExpanded' of undefined
    at CandidatesComponent_tr_51_Template (candidates.component.html:114)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7329)

Comment: I have updated the code even. Could you please verify once why I am facing this. I have added the variable 'isExpanded' but even then I am getting that error

Comment: I have clone that project to my machine, and its working fine. Have you integrated everything as suggested in that repository.
Github Repo : https://github.com/ipsjolly/FreakyJolly.com/tree/master/Demo/Angular/angular-expand-collapse-datatable

Comment: Adding isExpanded flag didn't worked for me..! I have used the following [link] https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzwqmw?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html and thank you so much for letting  me know that[ Note that this approach means you cannot include certain native-table features such colspan/rowspan or have columns that resize themselves based on their content]
1) After making the table with native HTML type.  Everything is working fine. :) :)
Thanks a lot for your time and suggestions..!! =D